# How to force the code to go to onErrorResponse in Volley JsonObjectRequest

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

A crash is reported in Volley JsonObjectRequest and exactly in its `onErrorResponse` block. I cannot change the webservice output to test `onErrorResponse` block and it's important to debug this code block.

Can anyone tell me how to force the code to go to this part?

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "MY_URL", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            // Which code should I add here to force the code to go to onErrorResponse

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            ...
            // I want to debug this code block

        }
    });
```

I tried `response = null;` in `onResponse` but it caused a crash and it didn't go to `onErrorResponse`.

Comment: try adding some invalid url

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Vivek Mishra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4562287/vivek-mishra) said in comments, I tried to set an invalid URL like `"https://stackoverflow.com/"` instead of `"MY_URL"` (which was a valid API URL), and it went to `onErrorResponse`.

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://google.com/", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        // OnResponse Codes

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        // OnError Codes

    }
});
```